# How to use UserOp1/UserOp2 instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

how to use LLVM [UserOp1](http://legup.eecg.utoronto.ca/doxygen-4.0/group__LLVMCCoreTypes.html#gga17a137327ed1a49585a00c585313ec18a5c953b19eccd6b86ed3b1a3bdfb8fef7)?

I can't find any examples of this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an instruction, but an opcode used internally in LLVM passes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind to ask one more question?  How do you think to count the instructions executed dynamically(dynamic instruction count)?  I have an idea is that defining 2 global variables @g1,@total, and inserting a special instruction(like count %arg1) before every BasicBlock, the special instruction do: 1. get @g1; 2.  %add=add %arg1,@g1 ;3.  %i1 = cmpugt %add, %total;  4. if %i1 is 1,  terminate the function, else   run the left real instructions.  I guess it would be work, but it would be complicated to add a new inst. Do you have any idea to share?